# Simple program to restart another program on certain condition

Tags: windows, utility, exit-code

Basically I need to restart a program if it quits with a value other than zero.

I believe it will be a simple program probably can be made with a few lines of code in a BAT file. I'm wondering if someone has already written similar program and want to share it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    rc = subprocess.call('program.exe')
    if rc == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example in Batch:

```
:a
program.exe
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO a
```